# ffmpeg does not copy custom metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying to fix some videos made with an iDevice. The videos have a rotation in the metadata which is only understood by Apple and its software but noone else. Fixing this is quite simple, but I also would like to keep the other metadata in the files like the geolocation.

I tried a couple of versions, all with the same result, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf vflip,hflip -map_metadata 0 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0  -acodec copy output.mp4
```

This should work, it already gives the correct preview of metadata:

```
ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb  8 2013 23:55:22 with Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2013-02-17 00.39.36.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
    model           : iPhone 5
    model-deu       : iPhone 5
    encoder         : 6.1
    encoder-deu     : 6.1
    date            : 2013-02-17T00:39:25+0100
    date-deu        : 2013-02-17T00:39:25+0100
    location        : +48.2683+007.7205+172.710/
    location-deu    : +48.2683+007.7205+172.710/
    make            : Apple
    make-deu        : Apple
  Duration: 00:00:09.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16764 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 16696 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/600 fr:24/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[libx264 @ 0x7fc248829a00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x7fc248829a00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fc248829a00] 264 - core 125 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2012 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : qt  
  minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: qt  
  creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
  model           : iPhone 5
  model-deu       : iPhone 5
  encoder-deu     : 6.1
  date            : 2013-02-17T00:39:25+0100
  date-deu        : 2013-02-17T00:39:25+0100
  location        : +48.2683+007.7205+172.710/
  location-deu    : +48.2683+007.7205+172.710/
  make            : Apple
  make-deu        : Apple
  encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
Metadata:
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
  creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
  rotate          : 0
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, mono, 61 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

But the resulting file keeps only some of these metadata tags:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4
```

shows:

```
fmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  8 2013 23:55:22 with Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.1.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads -  -enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
  creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
  date            : 2013-02-17T00:39:25+0100
  encoder         : Lavf54.59.106
Duration: 00:00:09.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3286 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3219 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 61 kb/s
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-02-16 23:39:25
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I also tried to add the one tag I'm interested in by hand with

```
-metadata:g location=+48.2683+007.7205+172.710/
```

with no change in the result.

Output as .mov doesn't change anything, neither.

Is there any trick to add non-standard metadata? How do I get the location back in there?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give some insight on this.

Comment: You trimmed the ffmpeg console output which cuts out potentially useful information.

Comment: I added all output now, hopefully it helps to find the problem

Answer (score 4):

The FFmpeg mp4 muxer only writes a select list of known metadata types. Some muxers, like AVI, will write all metadata fields using custom tags (partially to allow such remuxing use cases), but [movenc.c](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavformat/movenc.c;h=b6821d447c92183101086cb67099b2f4804293de;hb=HEAD) doesn't do that yet (see the code blocks in line 2911 or 3064). You could potentially implement it yourself.

Comment: Three years later still same, just the source has moved to Github [movenc.c #3511](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/movenc.c#L3511)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently FFMPEG has a documented bug about this issue:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4209